# SQL LIKE on Alias

Tags: sql, alias, where-clause

Is this possible?

I'm trying to do a SQL statement on an alias but getting an error...

```
SELECT 
      CASE PERSON_TYPE  WHEN 'PER' THEN LAST_NAME
                                   ELSE COMPANY_NAME
      END AS FULLNAME, *
FROM PERSON
[WHERE FULLNAME LIKE '%AN%'] // Error FULLNAME - INvalid COlumn Name
```

otherwise, this is the alternative I'm using....

```
WHERE (LAST_NAME LIKE '%AN%') OR (COMPANY_NAME LIKE '%AN%')
```

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible, at least in SQL Server. You need to use `CASE PERSON_TYPE WHEN 'PER' THEN LAST_NAME ELSE COMPANY_NAME END like '%AN%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two solutions.

One is to pass the FULLNAME to the WHERE CLAUSE like this:

```
SELECT 
      CASE PERSON_TYPE  WHEN 'PER' THEN LAST_NAME
                                   ELSE COMPANY_NAME
      END AS FULLNAME, PERSON.*
FROM PERSON
WHERE (PERSON_TYPE = 'PER' AND LAST_NAME LIKE '%AN%') OR (COMPANY_NAME LIKE '%AN%')
```

THe other is to make an INNER QUERY like this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT *, CASE PERSON_TYPE  
                  WHEN 'PER' THEN LAST_NAME 
                  ELSE COMPANY_NAME END AS FULLNAME
FROM PERSON ) t
WHERE t.FULLNAME LIKE '%AN%'
```

Comment: Noting this question has only the `sql` tag, neither of your queries conform with standard SQL. Suggestion on how to fix this: change `*` to `PERSON.*`.

Comment: @onedaywhen done! thanks for the suggestion, I used the query from the user so it will work on it as well.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, CASE PERSON_TYPE  
                  WHEN 'PER' THEN LAST_NAME 
                  ELSE COMPANY_NAME END AS FULLNAME
FROM PERSON ) t
WHERE FULLNAME LIKE '%AN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access field aliases in `WHERE`. Use derived tables/CTE as an alternative, or repeat the whole expression in `WHERE`. 
Trick for mysql : you can put it on `HAVING` without `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use alias in WHERE condition. BTW, you might also want to remove  ", *" from the select statement. That will also cause an error.